# How can I solve sound drops over HDMI in Raspbmc?

Tags: media, raspbmc

I'm using Raspbmc RC3 to play some  720/1080p content over NFS and AFP. I experience frequent sound drops, every 2-3 minutes or so the sound drops for 1-2 secs.

I've set XBMC to forward Dolby/DTS to my capable receiver, and set audio mode to 5.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've solved it:
Set video at 30Hz, do not adjust rate to match played files.
Turns out enabling passthrough, BUT setting audio at 2.0 gives me uninterrupted 5.1 AC3 and DTS on my receiver!

Comment: Well done, nice work :)

Comment: I will in 4 hours - can't accept it yet

Comment: I've also sorted it for 60Hz - I overclocked my Pi's cpu_freq to 900 and gpu_freq to 350.

Comment: * arm_freq instead of cpu_freq

Answer (score 11):

First, stop xbmc

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo initctl stop xbmc
```

go and get fbset

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo apt-get install fbset
```

take a look to the current framebuffer settings

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ fbset

mode "1920x1080"
    geometry 1920 1080 1920 1080 16
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 5/11,6/5,5/0,0/16
endmode
```

enable hardware acceleration, maybe to improve the xbmc GUI rendering and to enjoy some 3DDemos quite faster, dunno if the accel is needed but why not giving a try to learn something

```
fbset -accel true
```

now take a look again

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ fbset

mode "1920x1080"
    geometry 1920 1080 1920 1080 16
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    accel true
    rgba 5/11,6/5,5/0,0/16
endmode
```

ok, let's get git and build-essential

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo apt-get install git build-essential
```

clone the raspb firmware, this takes a lot of space ! ~600mb

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ git clone git://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware.git
```

now lets move some files where they should be

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ cd firmware/opt/vc
pi@raspbmc:~/firmware/opt/vc$ sudo mv bin /opt/vc/
pi@raspbmc:~/firmware/opt/vc$ sudo mv include /opt/vc/
pi@raspbmc:~/firmware/opt/vc$ sudo mv sbin /opt/vc/
pi@raspbmc:~/firmware/opt/vc$ sudo mv src /opt/vc/
```

tell our TV to switch to 1080p24 but first have a look to the supported resolutions of your TV

```
pi@raspbmc:~/firmware/opt/vc$ cd /opt/vc/bin
pi@raspbmc:/opt/vc/bin$ ./tvservice --modes=CEA
Group CEA has 15 modes:
           mode 1: 640x480 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 2: 720x480 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 3: 720x480 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 5: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz, interlaced
  (native) mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz, progressive
           mode 17: 720x576 @ 50Hz, progressive
           mode 18: 720x576 @ 50Hz, progressive
           mode 19: 1280x720 @ 50Hz, progressive
           mode 20: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz, interlaced
           mode 21: 720x576 @ 50Hz, interlaced
  (native) mode 31: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz, progressive
           mode 32: 1920x1080 @ 24Hz, progressive
           mode 33: 1920x1080 @ 25Hz, progressive
           mode 34: 1920x1080 @ 30Hz, progressive
pi@raspbmc:/opt/vc/bin$
```

ok mode 32 is the one for me what i was looking for

```
pi@raspbmc:/opt/vc/bin$ ./tvservice --explicit="CEA 32"
Powering on HDMI with explicit settings (CEA mode 32)
pi@raspbmc:/opt/vc/bin$
```

let's check

```
pi@raspbmc:/opt/vc/bin$ ./tvservice -s
state: HPD high|HDMI mode|HDCP off|composite off (0x12001a), 1920x1080 @ 24Hz, progressive
pi@raspbmc:/opt/vc/bin$
```

yeah done, start xbmc

```
pi@raspbmc:/opt/vc/bin$ sudo initctl start xbmc
```

enjoy flicker free movies like a mediacenter should do

oh, and try out the demos in /opt/vc/src !

Comment: wow fantastic answer!

Comment: I see you install build-essential, but then I don't see you use any build tools. Are the binaries in the git check out, or did you miss the `make` command?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by editing the file ~/.xbmc/userdata/guisettings.xml and setting to true these properties:

```
<dtshdpassthrough default="true">true</dtshdpassthrough>
<dtspassthrough default="true">true</dtspassthrough>
<dualaudio default="true">true</dualaudio>
```

Hope this can be useful for someone.

Greetings,